# covering of a topological space that has coverings with $n$ sheets.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Let $X$ be locally path-connected, path-connected, and semilocally simply connected by paths. Suppose that $X$ admits a covering with $n$ sheets for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Show then that $X$ admits a covering with infinitely many sheets.

I do this:

We know that $X$ admits a universal covering that covers all the covering with $n$ sheets for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and so the subgroup corresponding to the universal covering (i.e., the trivial one) has an index greater than the indices of the subgroups corresponding to coverings with $n$ sheets, which have an index of $n$. However, this implies that the subgroup corresponding to the universal covering has an infinite index, and therefore the universal covering has an infinite number of sheets.

i want to know if the demonstration is good

Comment: What is your question? The proof you gave works fine, even if it could perhaps be worded a little more concisely.

Comment: i want to know if the demonstration as good

Comment: Then please put that into the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument looks fine.

Technically I guess that when the $n$-fold covering factors through the universal covering, that shows that the degree of the universal covering is $\ge n$, not $> n$ as you suggest. But the argument works the same.